# Can I add an older Object Library to my Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, vba

Well basically I just wanted to know wether or not it was possible to add an older object library to excel 2013 and if so, How can I go about adding it? Im looking for object library 12.0

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the "Excel 12.0 Object Library", the "Office 12.0 Object Library" or some other 12.0 object library?

Comment: @barrowc actually I need the PowerPoint 12.0 Library...

Comment: Is PowerPoint 2007 (which corresponds to the 12.0 library) installed on the machine in question?

Comment: No 2013 is the only one I have.

Comment: Are you having a functionality issue (i.e. version 12 does something differently to version 14) or a distribution issue (i.e. some of your intended users are on older versions of Office and don't have the same version 14 library that you do - thus causing your program to fail on their machines)?

Comment: Actually I'm running a Macro on Excel 2007 at work but the same Macro on my laptop, and I'm running Excel 2013, doesn't execute it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is something called "late binding." You should create your objects in the following format:

```
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Rather than:

```
Dim olApp as Outlook.Application
```

Sources:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=244167
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115
http://excel.tips.net/T003340_Automatically_Changing_References_to_VBA_Libraries.html
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/723006-using-outlook-object-library-excel-visual-basic-applications-supporting-older-versions.html

Comment: @William you can check this [link](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/EarlyLateBinding.html) as well. It uses power point as example.